# Determine what device was used for a Google search

Tags: google-chrome

Giving that I have 2-3 devices all signed in using the same Google account so that the searchhistory is synced between the devices. Is it possible to determine (i.e. Acces the info somewhere) which device was used for a specific search?

Answer (score 0):

Go to [myactivity](https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity) and find which search you want more details on and then click on details. It will show you details like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oItnI.png)

Comment: Thank You! But it Will only give me information on what OS that was used? So if I’m using 2 iOS devices it’s not possible to determine which one was used?

Comment: If search is via the app, it should show the device name. If browser, I don't see how one can differentiate except location.